# Docker error while PULL - Error downloading dependent layers

Tags: linux, docker, linux-mint, lxc

I get the following error when pulling a image

```
docker pull ubuntu

Pulling repository ubuntu
c0fe63f9a4c1: Error pulling image (latest) from ubuntu, read tcp 162.159.253.251:443: connection reset by peer 
e20bcab99567: Error pulling image (lucid) from ubuntu, unexpected EOF 
f697cdc2ef19: Error pulling image (quantal) from ubuntu, flate: read error at offset 806906: read tcp 162.159.253.251:443: connection reset by peer 
25593492b938: Error pulling image (saucy) from ubuntu, read tcp 162.159.253.251:443: connection reset by peer 
ab4344e23e3a: Error pulling image (13.04) from ubuntu, flate: read error at offset 585714: read tcp 162.159.253.251:443: connection reset by peer 
511136ea3c5a: Download complete 
9a8b9d29f4fc: Download complete 
01bdd5cc09de: Download complete 
13dec63ebd94: Error downloading dependent layers 
6170bb7b0ad1: Download complete 
79fdb1362c84: Error downloading dependent layers 
1c7f181e78b9: Download complete 
d0732e6ce563: Error downloading dependent layers 
f323cf34fd77: Download complete 
9109d385566e: Error downloading dependent layers 
2014/04/13 04:21:18 Could not find repository on any of the indexed registries.
```

Comment: Have you tried multiple times? Do you get the same error each time?

Comment: Yes, tried multiple times and get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

How fast is your internet connection? I got the same error and believe it to be associated with a timeout because of slow internet. Multiple attempts worked...

Answer (score 0):

Try running it as root. I am getting the same error when running the command as a non-privileged user. When I ran it as root, it worked fine.

```
sudo docker pull ubuntu
```

Comment: Non-privileged user should give a socket error. Most default environments won't let you download unless you are root